# PHP header location-redirect doesn't work - why?

Tags: php, http-headers, xdebug

Here's my file. I want to make it redirect, but nothing happens. To check out what is going on, I added an echo before the header part.

It neither throws an error or redirect to index.php. What is wrong?
I have turned output buffering on/off, but nothing makes it redirect. What can I do?

```
<?
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo 'This is an error';

header("Location: login.php");
die();
?>
```

Comment: Is *display\_errors* enabled?

Comment: Does the code you've provided at least output 'This is an error'?

Comment: No it didn't, but it all had to do with Xdebug breaking up the headers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reminded myself that I had xDebug installed on the actual test environment and after googling it, I found this site: http://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=532

So I'll downloaded the last version of xDebug and changed the php.ini accordingly for the new file and everything works out like a charm. Headers are being sent - the redirecetion is done and errors are displayed.

Thanks everybody for your help!

Answer (score 52):

From [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) :

`header()` must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.

And in your case, you are using `echo` before `header()`

Comment: I know that and thats why I have made an echo before the header()-call. It makes an error at other servers and should do this. Why doesn't anything happen?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have short tags enabled?
try it with the long tag `<?php`:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
header("Location: login.php");
die();
?>
```

Comment: Yep, I do have short tags set enabled, and everything else works fine, except the header stuff...

Answer (score 0):

> Is display_errors enabled?
>   @Gumbo - It sure is!

well, it sure is not. because

> To check out what is going on, I added an echo before the header part.

if you'd have display_errors enabled, it would display an error, at least when you `turned output buffering on`.

So, first of all make sure you can see error messages.
just print out an undefined variable,

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo $undef9306;
```

I am sure you won't see it.
So, you have to turn displaying errors on

Next, on the server side you can use `headers_sent()` function to see if headers were sent. On client side use HTTP sniffer to see if anything were sent

And check your file for the BOM.

Comment: Hi. I'm afraid not. Display_errors are enabled as said, but it was the xDebug that caused this... Thanks a lot for your help Col.!