# PHP Header not redirecting

Tags: php, header

My header won't redirect. After the code is executed it's just blank and doesn't execute the redirect. There's no whitespace in the file. The code works completely correctly apart from the redirect.

This code is called by a form submit.

```
if(!empty($_POST['addSubscriber'])){
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  if(!empty($name) && !empty($email) && eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $email) != FALSE){
    $conn = connect();
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM subscribers WHERE email=?";
    if($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)){
      $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
      $stmt->execute();
      if($stmt->fetch()){
        header("Location: http://bcp350.org.uk/index.php?message=1");
      } else {
        $password = md5(uniqid());
        $sql2 = "INSERT INTO subscribers(name, email, password) VALUES(?, ?, '$password')";
        if($stmt2 = $conn->prepare($sql2)){
          $stmt2->bind_param("ss", $name, $email);
          $stmt2->execute();
          if($stmt2->affected_rows == 1)
            header("Location: http://bcp350.org.uk/index.php?message=1");
        }
      }
    }
  } else {
    header("Location: urlnotallowedbecauseofstackoverflowlimit");
  }
}
```

Comment: After which `header()` call does it fail?  Also, **always** call `exit();` right after doing `header("Location:");` to stop further execution of the current script!`

Comment: Is there something before the posted code in the *.php-file?

Comment: Put in the `exit()` calls after each of your your header redirects and see if it still fails.  If it doesn't, then it's possible an error further down the page is still being executed and failing.

Comment: By the code logic, redirection will be executed not in any case - there is 2 `if`s, when redirection will not be called.

Comment: The full php file that this code snippet is included in can be viewed here pastebin.com/Ha4LQu24

Comment: I might add that if I put a echo here instead that that executes fine, it's just if it's a header.

Comment: It was whitespace in constants.php, thanks a lot though guys!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP header location-redirect doesn't work - why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710079/php-header-location-redirect-doesnt-work-why)

Answer (score 8):

According to the PHP documentation for [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include(), or require(), functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file

Are you sure there is no output sent to the page prior to calling `header`?

Comment: The full php file that this code snippet is included in can be viewed here http://pastebin.com/Ha4LQu24

Comment: @Nick, but what about in `constants.php` ? You must also verify there's no whitespace in that file.

Answer (score 3):

If any of the following happens in your code, all calls to `header()` will be bypassed:

1. $_POST['addSubscriber'] is empty
2. $conn->prepare($sql) returns falsy
3. $conn->prepare($sql2) returns falsy
4. $stmt2->affected_rows does not compare to 1

You need to add some debugging and figure out which of those is happening.

Answer (score -1):

use this code in the very beginning of your php page

```
<?php
```

ob_start();
?>