# how i use of header tag to redirect page in php

Tags: php, redirect

I want to redirect the page on the if condition.

this is my html page

```
<form name="frmpayment" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="payment_mode.php" method="POST">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td><label for="mode">Select Mode</label></td>
    <td>
   <select name="selectmode" id="slctmode" size="1">
   <option selected>Selected Mode</option>
   <option value="1">Online Payment</option>
   <option value="2">Cash on Delevery</option>
    </select></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>
    <input type="submit" name="btnmode" value="Done"/> 
         </td></tr></table>

    </form>
```

and this is my payment_mode.php page

```
<?php
$i= $_POST['selectmode'];

if($i>1)
    {
        header("Location : detail.php");

    }
else
    {
        header("Location : home.php");

    }

?>
```

bt it does not redirect the page detail.php and home.php

Comment: Probably because you echo something earlier. Check out this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710079/php-header-location-redirect-doesnt-work-why

Comment: Do you have any error messages?

Comment: thnx everybody for reply I solve the problem the correct to the target path of form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<?php
$i= $_POST['selectmode'];

if($i>1)
    {
        header("Location: detail.php");
        exit;

    }
else
    {
        header("Location : home.php");
        exit;

    }
```

Also, make sure on this page there is nothing being outputted before your calling the `header()` function.